# removeIf implementation detail

Tags: java, java-8, iterator

I have a small implementation detail question that I fail to understand in `ArrayList::removeIf`. I don't think I can simply put it the way it is without some preconditions first.

As such: the implementation is basically a *bulk* `remove`, unlike `ArrayList::remove`. An example should make things a lot easier to understand. Let's say I have this list:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(); // 2, 4, 6, 5, 5
list.add(2);
list.add(4);
list.add(6);
list.add(5);
list.add(5);
```

And I would like to remove every element that is even. I could do:

```
Iterator<Integer> iter = list.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    int elem = iter.next();
    if (elem % 2 == 0) {
         iter.remove();
    }
}
```

*Or* :

```
list.removeIf(x -> x % 2 == 0);
```

The result will be the same, but the implementation is very different. Since the `iterator` is a view of the `ArrayList`, every time I call `remove`, the underlying `ArrayList` has to be brought to a "good" state, meaning that the inner array will actually change. Again, on every single call of `remove`, there will be calls `System::arrayCopy` internally.

On the contrast `removeIf` is smarter. Since it does the iteration internally, it can make things more optimized. The way it does this is interesting.

It first computes the indexes where the elements are supposed to be removed from. This is done by first computing a tiny `BitSet`, an array of `long` values where at each index, resides a `64 bit` value (a `long`). Multiple `64 bit` values make this a `BitSet`. To set a value at a particular offset, you first need to find out the index in the array and then set the corresponding bit. This is not very complicated. Let's say you want to set bit 65 and 3. First we need a `long [] l = new long[2]` (because we went beyond 64 bits, but not more than 128):

```
|0...(60 more bits here)...000|0...(60 more bits here)...000|
```

You first find the index : `65 / 64` (they actually do `65 >> 6`) and then in that index (`1`) put the needed bit:

```
1L << 65 // this will "jump" the first 64 bits, so this will actually become 00000...10.
```

Same thing for `3`. As such that long array will become:

```
|0...(60 more bits here)...010|0...(60 more bits here)...1000|
```

In source code they call this BitSet - `deathRow` (nice name!).

---

Let's take that `even` example here, where `list = 2, 4, 6, 5, 5`

- they iterate the array and compute this `deathRow` (where `Predicate::test` is `true`).

> deathRow = 7 (000... 111)
>
> meaning indexes = [0, 1, 2] are to be removed

- they now replace elements in the underlying array based on that deathRow (not going into the details how this is done)

> inner array becomes : [5, 5, 6, 5, 5]. Basically they move the elements that are supposed to remain in front of the array.

---

**I can finally bring in the question.**

At this point in time, they know:

```
 w   ->  number of elements that have to remain in the list (2)
 es  ->  the array itself ([5, 5, 6, 5, 5])
 end ->  equal to size, never changed
```

To me, there is a single step to do here :

```
void getRidOfElementsFromWToEnd() {
    for(int i=w; i<end; ++i){
       es[i] = null;
    }
    size = w;
}
```

Instead, this happens:

```
private void shiftTailOverGap(Object[] es, int w, int end) {
    System.arraycopy(es, end, es, w, size - end);
    for (int to = size, i = (size -= end - w); i < to; i++)
        es[i] = null;
}
```

I've renamed the variables on purpose here.

What is the point in calling:

```
 System.arraycopy(es, end, es, w, size - end);
```

Especially `size - end`, since `end` *is* `size` all the time - it is never changed (so this is always `zero`). This is basically a NO-OP here. What corner case am I missing here?

Comment: I just wasted 1/2 a day understanding these details, and this is so obvious, this method is used in _other_ places too. I am an idiot :|

Comment: Honestly, you left me confused. Was your question around the use of `System.arraycopy(es, end, es, w, size - end)` as the underlying implementation details of `removeIf`? I almost felt like, I was reading an answer to some other question in between. (Reading the comment above) I sense it ended up in a trivial question finally. Is that so?

Comment: @Naman exactly, it was about that dreaded `System.arrayCopy`. Nevertheless it was a fun journey through the details ( that internal bit set turns out to have the same idea as `java.util.BitSet`)

Comment: @Naman if you want you can provide an answer where that is _not_ a NOOP ( hint: `range`...) and I will accept it.

Comment: @Eugene in Java 8, it does use `java.util.BitSet`. To me, the re-implementation of the `BitSet` operations doesn’t look significantly better than the original. The opportunity to skip entire words has been missed.

Comment: @Holger thank you, indeed I was looking at java-13.

Comment: @Holger I found out today that Doug Lea himself wrote that internal bitset and when I asked (at the conference) that there is an opportunity missed (according to your comment and my observation afterwards), the answer was : "we know. may be in a future version". I found this rather interesting.

Comment: @Eugene more than that missed opportunity, it annoys me that the JDK 9+ `List.of(…)`, `Set.of(…)`, `Map.of(…)` immutable collections still have no dedicated `forEach` nor `spliterator()` implementations, even in JDK 15.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking at the specific (common) case that the list, you call `removeIf` on, is the same as the `ArrayList`. Only in this case, you can assume that `end` is always equal to `size`.

A counter-example would be:

```
ArrayList<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7));
l.subList(2, 5).removeIf(i -> i%2 == 1);
```

Likewise, `removeAll` will call `shiftTailOverGap` with an `end` argument which can differ from `size` when being applied to a `subList`.

A similar situation arises when you call `clear()`. In that case, the actual operation, performed when calling it on the `ArrayList` itself, is so trivial that it does not even calls the `shiftTailOverGap` method. Only when using something like `l.subList(a, b).clear()`, it’ll end up at `removeRange(a, b)` on `l`, which will in turn, as you already found out yourself, invoke `shiftTailOverGap(elementData, a, b)` with a `b`which can be smaller than `size`.